SailsJS Does Not Invoke Controller Action When URL Ends With File Extension
SailsJS Does Not Invoke Controller Action When URL Ends With File Extension
I have a route set up to handle requests to an image...
./config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  ...,
  '/api/v1/uploads/products/:productId/:filename': 'image',
};

I have that controller/action in my controllers. However, I get a 404 when visiting the url...
http:localhost:1337/api/v1/uploads/products/87a5sdfaas7/as78a8sb8h7.png
However, when I visit...
http:localhost:1337/api/v1/uploads/products/87a5sdfaas7/test
... I do hit my controller. But if I visit...
http:localhost:1337/api/v1/uploads/products/87a5sdfaas7/test.png
...then I get a 404 again.
It seems that Sails bails out of any routing as soon as it encounters anything that looks like a file. I believe this Sails, itself, and not Express as I believe I've used routes like this in ExpressJS before.
Is there a way to explicitly tell Sails "This may look like a file but DON'T abandon the router and still hit my controller for this"? How do you get around this?

A Workaround
As I was writing the question, I came up with a useful workaround. Here's how I redefined my route...
./config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  ...,
  '/api/v1/uploads/products/:productId/:filename/image': 'image',
};

That's basically it. Now Sails doesn't abandon the router. Hope that helps!
